# Call to undefined function fetch_row()

Tags: php, mysql

Im connecting to database:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
mysql_select_db("mydb");
```

And when I try to get a row using within a for each with this code:

```
$question = fetch_row("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE PyetjaNr = $i ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ");
```

Im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_row()
```

Same code is working in my hosting server (mysql 5.5),
but not working in my localhost mysql (5.6),

Is problem to mysql version? can I do anything except upgrading to mysqli?

Comment: `fetch_row()` should be `mysql_fetch_row()`

Comment: @Sean Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: You need to [query](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) before you can fetch.

Comment: you need to do `mysql_query()` on your query 1st, and then `mysql_fetch_row` - ie. `$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM \`mytable\` WHERE PyetjaNr = $i ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 "); $results = mysql_fetch_row($question);`

Comment: did you create a custom function `function fetch_row()` that did both `mysql_query()` && `mysql_fetch_row()`, but did not upload that function file to your hosting server? that would be the only reason why it worked on localhost, but not on your hosting server

Comment: yes I have this: function fetch_row() {
  $numargs = func_num_args();
  $arg_list = func_get_args();
  $format = $arg_list[0];
  $clean_arg_list = array();

  for ($i = 1; $i < $numargs; $i++)
    array_push($clean_arg_list, qstrip($arg_list[$i]));

  $SQL = vsprintf($format, $clean_arg_list);

  $R = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($SQL), MYSQL_ASSOC);

  return $R;
}

Comment: Is your `function fetch_row()` defined/included somewhere before you call `$question = fetch_row(...)`?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: For starters, you must specify if you are using custom functions, and please make sure the file where that function is defined is included .  mysqli_* functions are deprecated as of version 5.5.0 (as per manual on php.net)

Comment: @ShailendraPatel - Nope. `mysqli_` functions are still fine; it's the `mysql_` functions that are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed this in the PHP manual (in which case, you should read the manual for functions you use), but the `mysql_...` functions are deprecated, and will almost certainly not even be in 5.7 when it comes out. They were replaced with the `mysqli_...` set of functions, so use those instead.

The PHP manual for [mysqli::set_charset](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) covers the initial setup you need, and getting data out of your db is then simply a matter of [querying it the normal way](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Which usually means making use of prepared statements instead of just building your SQL as a string (because you want to be secure, you don't want to be [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Wipe what you have now, redo it with `mysqli` functions. If your problem still exists, at least now you'll have modern code that people can comment on for putting in your question.